# no styles rendered with root route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I came on this weird Rails issue: I added a root route to my route.rb file

```
root :to => 'pages#home'
```

however, when I enter:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

in the browser, the css styles for my home page do not show.

The odd thing is, that when I go to:

```
http://localhost:3000/home
```

the css does get rendered.

I'm using Rails 4.1.0

does anyone know what could be the problem?

ps:

my application.html.erb code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mysite</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= render "layouts/header" %>

<%= yield %>

<%= render "layouts/footer" %>

</body>
</html>
```

The header of my rendered page:

```
http://localhost:3000
```

looks like this:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Anthony Candaele</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

</head>
```

However, when I go to:

```
http://localhost:3000/home
```

the header source of the rendered page looks like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Mysite</title>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  <meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
  <meta content="UAWpX6x35EzVFSFyNPsaPPdE/0kEWqBQStCs9qWtOGc=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
```

Comment: did your CSS did not load or your HTML does not have the CSS file references?

Comment: I check through Chrome Dev tools and it seems that nothing from the /css or /images folders is loaded. The strange thing is that when I go to: http://localhost:3000/home then the css and images are loaded

Comment: show your application.html and your head section of page source

Comment: ok, I added the application.html.erb code and head section of the page source to my question above

Comment: does your head element changes between localhost and localhost/home

Comment: yes it seems so, I added the page source header code in my question above

Comment: I got it finally solved. The issue was caused by a index.html file that still was lingering in the public/ folder. I put it there for testing purposes. By removing this file, my root directive in config/route.rb is working fine now. Thanks emaillenin for your help.